# Connect to TFS in web server using Windows authentication

Tags: tfs

We have a WebAPI project that exposes a few controllers doing tasks with TFS. We usually connect like this:

```
var server = 
    new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("http://XXX"));
server.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

My understanding of this is: It works because somehow, my IIS express runs the application under my account. Somehow the TfsConfigurationServer can read my credentials and use them when querying/writing over TFS.

Now, the problem comes when I try to host this in a real webserver. Comes back with:

```
"TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://XXX"
```

I have activated Windows Authentication, so if I print:

```
User.Identity.Name -> (domain\\my_user).
```

Even being there my username, it does not seem to be enough. I assumed the TfsConfigurationServer class can't get the credentials, so I've tried to be more explicit:

```
new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("XXX"), CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
```

Didn't work either. I was assuming that, given that I have Windows Authentication activated and Anonymous deactivated, DefaultNetworkCredentials would work. Reading more I've found also:

```
var id = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;
using (id.Impersonate())
{
    return myOperation.CallMethod();
}
```

But same result. Inside CallMethod() I was calling again TfsConfigurationServer with the DefaultNetworkCredentials. The impersonation seems to be working fine, but authentication to TFS fails anyway.

**How can I provide the credentials to TFS from the currently logged in user in the server via Windows Auth?. How does it work in local?.**

Note: I have been reading also about TFS Impersonation (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taylaf/2009/12/04/introducing-tfs-impersonation/). My problem is that it seems to require some permissions set in the server, I'd love to mimic that behavior without using this technique, not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try with below code:

```
 var tfsCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials, true);
    TfsTeamProjectCollection teamCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfssite.com/tfs/" + Collection), tfsCredentials);
```

Comment: I really really appreciate @Patrick-MSFT, unfortunately it did not work. The weirdest thing is that I have activated ASP.NET impersonation in the server (IIS 8, but adding validateIntegratedModeConfiguration=false). After that, it will start working if previously I log on the server using remote desktop and call to the url there :O. It works for a couple of minutes.